# How to update a dictionary value when a variable changes inside a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x = 2
dict_1 = {'One': x}

def my_fun():
    global x
    x = 1

my_fun()

print('x is: ', x, '| dict_1 is :', dict_1)
```

Output is :

```
x is:  1 | dict_1 is : {'One': 2}
```

How can I reflect the change in a variable in dictionary value?

Comment: Is that your actual use-case? Do you actually need `dict_1` to exist before calling `my_fun`? Is there a reason why `my_fun` modifies a global? This is generally an anti-pattern. Does `my_func` "know" that `dict_1` exists and depends on it, or are they separate/modular? Do you need `dict_1` to be the same object before and after calling `my_fun`, or would it be okay to create a new `dict_1`?

Comment: x is a variable that takes user input. There are several functions that runs taking dictionary value from dict_1. I want the value of 'one' in the dictionary to always refer to x, and x in turn changes with user input. In summary, I want reflect a change in x instantaneously in dict_1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do `dict_1['One'] = x = 1` so you reassign both? There's no magic way to make this happen; once `dict_1` is constructed, it has no further relationship to the name `x`, and the object `x` refers to (an `int`) is immutable, so you can't do anything to take advantage of `x` and `dict_1['One']` being aliases to the same object (initially).

There are all sorts of terrible solutions to do something like this (making the value of `dict_1` a `lambda` that returns `x`, making `dict_1` a function that constructs the `dict` with the current `x`, using module level `__getattr__` instead of defining `dict_1` such that loading `dict_1` gets a freshly constructed `dict`, etc.), but all of them require some additional steps that would make `print('x is: ', x, '| dict_1 is :', dict_1)` not work as written, or make `dict_1` not persistent, or both.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the constraints are in your question, or what exactly you're trying to achieve, but one way to solve the problem is to adjust your code so it looks like this:

```
global x, dict_1
x = 2
dict_1 = {'One': x}

def my_fun():
    dict_1['One'] = x

x = 1
my_fun()
print('x is: ', x, '| dict_1 is :', dict_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think most people would do something like this. The keyword 'global' is very rarely appropriate.

```py
x = 2
dict_1 = {'One': x}

def my_fun(dictionary):
    dictionary['One'] = 1
    return dictionary

dict_1 = my_fun(dict_1)
x = dict_1['One']

print('x is: ', x, '| dict_1 is :', dict_1)
```

You want data sources to be authoritative. So there should be one data structure that holds the value and then code goes to that data structure for values. You can put them in variables or other data structures for convenience.